# How to use pagination in microsoft graph api in a react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, microsoft-graph-api

I am using microsoft graph API to get all my users data.

I need to expand and get the manager of each user.

You can't use 'search' or even' top' filter when you use 'expand' in microsoft graph api so I have filtered my response.value.

I have multiple users, so I need to use pagination to get all users.

My users request give me  :

- A response with the users data (array of object)
- 'oadata.nextLink' string.
  odata.nextLink contains a link with the next users data (like a pagination).

I have made a useEffect to get users Datas. In this useEffect, I first acquire a token and then get my users datas.

When I get the users data, I want to set the previous datas and the next one to get All datas from each nextLink.

Here my useEffect

```
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(
    'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$select=id,department,givenName,mail,displayName,userPrincipalName&$expand=manager($select=displayName)'
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated && softSkills?.length > 0) {
      function RequestProfileData() {
        const request = {
          ...loginRequest,
          account: accounts[0],
        };

        instance
          .acquireTokenSilent(request)
          .then(async (response) => {
 
          
            do {
              callMsGraphAndGetUsers(response.accessToken, url).then(
                (response) => {
                  const data = response?.value?.filter(
                    (user) =>
                      user?.mail !== null &&
                      !user?.mail?.includes('labo-systemsolutions.com') &&
                      (user.department === '1' ||
                        user.department === '2' ||
                        user.department === '3' ||
                        user.department === '4' ||
                        user.department === '5')
                  );  
                  
                     dispatch(setAllMicrosoftUsers(data));
                  
                  if (response['@odata.nextLink']) {
                    setUrl(response['@odata.nextLink']);
                  } else {
                    setUrl(null); 
                  }                }
              );
            } while (response['@odata.nextLink']);
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            instance.acquireTokenRedirect(request).then((response) => {
console.log(e)
            });
          });
      }
      RequestProfileData();
    } else {
      setGraphData(null);
    }
  }, [

//contains dependencies from other call in the useEffect
    isAuthenticated,
    tcgSkills,
    salesSkills,
    softSkills,
    adminSkills,
    loadingTcgSkills,
    loadingSalesSkills,
    loadingAdminSkills,
  ]);
```

here is my seState :

```
  setAllMicrosoftUsers: (state, action) => {
      const newUsers = action.payload;
      const existingUsers = new Set(
        state.allMicrosoftUsers.map((user) => user.id)
      );
      // Filter out duplicates before adding new users to the state
      const uniqueNewUsers = newUsers.filter(
        (user) => !existingUsers.has(user.id)
      );

      state.allMicrosoftUsers = state.allMicrosoftUsers.concat(uniqueNewUsers);
    },
```

here my callMsGraphAndGetUsers function :

```
import { graphConfig } from './authConfig';

export async function callMsGraphAndGetUsers(accessToken, url) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  const bearer = `Bearer ${accessToken}`;

  headers.append('Authorization', bearer);
  headers.append('ConsistencyLevel', 'eventual');
  headers.append('Prefer', 'legacySearch=false');
  const options = {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: headers,
  };

  return fetch(url, options)
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .catch((error) => console.log(error));
}
```

The problem : I only get the first data from A to D.

I have already tried to updated the setState, to log the urls and the response but I think I am doing something wrong in the do while .